# React: certain console.log statements skipped in useMemo hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, console.log, react-usememo

I'm encountering some weird behavior in a custom React `useMemo` hook. I'm trying to confirm that the correct values are being returned (as there's some evidence elsewhere that I'm getting the wrong value back), but I can't inspect using a developer console because the code is getting injected in a way that I can't attach to. (Oh well.)

I have a custom hook defined as follows (with all the relevant `console.log` statements in place for debugging):

```js
const defaultMargins = {...}

export const usePanelDimensions = (width: number, height: number, panelCount: number, panelSpacing: number, margins?: Margins) => {
    return useMemo(() => {
        console.log(`Default margins are ${JSON.stringify(defaultMargins)}`)
        console.log(`Received margins are ${JSON.stringify(margins)}`)
        console.log(`Received width ${width} and height ${height}`)
        const netHorizontalMargin = (margins?.left ?? defaultMargins.left) + (margins?.right ?? defaultMargins.right)
        const netVerticalMargin = (margins?.top ?? defaultMargins.top) + (margins?.bottom ?? defaultMargins.bottom)
        const netPanelSpacing = (panelSpacing * (panelCount - 1))
        console.log(`Net margins: ${netHorizontalMargin} ${netVerticalMargin} ${netPanelSpacing}`)
        const panelWidth = width - netHorizontalMargin
        const panelHeight = (height - netVerticalMargin - netPanelSpacing) / panelCount
        console.log(`-------`)
        console.log(`** panel width ${panelWidth}`)
        console.log(`** should report panel width as ${width - netHorizontalMargin}`)
        console.log(`** Returning panel width ${panelWidth} and panel height ${panelHeight}`)
        console.log(`-----`)
        return {panelWidth, panelHeight}
    }, [width, height, panelCount, panelSpacing, margins])
}
```

So here we are trying to divide a drawing space into one or more equal-sized bands, offset by some vertical distance.

We receive the overall canvas dimension (read from the rendered component), as well as a number of panels, the space between the panels, and some optional margins. If the margins aren't set, we use some defaults.

We compute the total width of one panel as the input width, less the left and right margins. The height of each panel is the height of the canvas, less the top and bottom margins, then divided into `panelCount` equal-sized units with `panelSpacing` pixels between them.

But when I run this, I get output for all the `console.log` statements *except* the ones between the dashed lines. Those statements are skipped entirely. Not "the variable interpolation leaves the values out," just the console log doesn't happen at all.

I understand that React sometimes suppresses console logging on second render when StrictMode is on (see https://camunda.com/blog/2021/02/be-careful-with-console-log-when-using-react-strictmode/) but I don't think strict mode is active here.

I considered that the problem might have something to do with some of the values not being set on first render. However, the line `** should report panel width ...` is printing a value (`width - netHorizontalMargin`) which is a direct computation on two values that both get printed successfully a few lines up.

I'm kind of at a loss as to a) why these output statements are getting ignored, and b) how to confirm the value that's actually getting returned, as the hook's consumer also can't display information about these computed values.

##### Edit

CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-cdn-0k7chz?file=/src/App.js

Not *quite* a MWE because obviously there's more code here than there needs to be, but this will show the behavior in question. The code at the CodeSandbox link runs without a problem (printing out the computed values between the `---` sections) on Firefox 104.0.1 (Ubuntu snap), where I get output:

```
Default margins are {"left":30,"right":15,"top":20,"bottom":50}
Received margins are {"left":50,"right":25,"top":30,"bottom":50}
Received width 2700 and height 475
Net margins: 75 80 0
-------
** panel width 2625
** should report panel width as 2625
** Returning panel width 2625 and panel height 395
-----
```

The issue does reproduce on Chrome 105.0.5195.102 (official Ubuntu 64-bit build), where I see output:

```
Default margins are {"left":30,"right":15,"top":20,"bottom":50}
Received margins are {"left":50,"right":25,"top":30,"bottom":50}
Received width 2700 and height 475
Net margins: 75 80 0
-------
-----
```

Before I go filing a bug report against React and/or Chrome, though, has anybody else encountered this behavior or have an explanation for why it might be expected/intended?

Comment: Could you try to reproduce the issue on codesandbox?

Comment: So, really dumb question, but knowing that sometimes stuff renders THEN runs use effects and whatnot, and not knowing how you call this...is there any possibility that panel count is 0? I wonder if a divide by zero exception is being swallowed and you don't see it.

Comment: @Nikki9696 good question. The panel count is hard-coded to 1 in the context where I'm seeing this behavior, though, so I know it isn't a div-by-zero issue. (Still possible I'm getting some other exception that's being swallowed, though!)

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Good suggestion. I'll edit the answer with the link.

Comment: The output that I see in the console I got https://gist.github.com/KonradLinkowski/8c3c5aca4964f7a5b1a936ea6113bb29 I probably don't understand the issue

Comment: @KonradLinkowski that's the output I would see in Firefox, but for some reason in Chrome the output is missing the stuff between the ---- lines. Are you saying this is the output you're getting in Chrome? (At this point I think the issue may be a bug in a particular Chrome version, unless there's some edge case in React's intended behavior that would cause this.)

Comment: Yes, I am using chrome

Comment: Thanks @KonradLinkowski -- looks like this must be a weird bug with particular versions of chrome. I'll see about filing an issue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was down to an old filtering statement in the console. The keywords in question probably shouldn't have impacted these variables, but removing it clears up the problem, so there you are.